# Unexpected output when accessing array element

Tags: bash, shell, array

I am using terminal with MacOSX.

I read this [entry](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-using-arrays.htm) introducing about unix array. I tried to access an array as its way, but failed:

```
a=(1,2) && echo "${a[0]}"
```

this is the output:

```
1,2
```

What I expected is `1`.

What should I do?

Comment: On Zsh I get nothing output. As this is a bash question, it is maybe worth noting for ZSH users who came by accidentally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`a=('1' '2') && echo "${a[0]}"` would be better like this.

In your version you only created a one element array which contains the value "1,2".

Comment: The quotes aren't necessary, just the whitespace (not a comma) to create two items instead of one.

Answer (score 3):

Three things to remember while accessing an element in an index array:

## 1. Normal expression - hardcoded index

```
arr=(one two three)
element_0="${arr[0]}"
```

## 2. Normal expression - index stored in a variable

```
arr=(it is cool to write readable code)
for ((i=0; i < ${#arr[@]}; i++)); do
    current_element=${arr[i]} # note, no '$' necessary before i
done
```

## 3. Arithmetic expression involving array elements

```
arr=(100 150 350)
((sum_of_first_two = arr[0] + arr[1])) # no need for '{ }'
```

Answer (score -1):

Although your *actual* problem was different from what the question title indicates (your approach to accessing the array item was correct), here are some general remarks on how to work with bash arrays.

From the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html)

> Any element of an array may be referenced using `${name[subscript]}`.
>   The braces are required to avoid conflicts with the shell’s filename
>   expansion operators.

...

> The subscript is treated as an arithmetic expression that must
>   evaluate to a number.

This implies that no `$` is necessary in the subscript.

> If the subscript used to reference an element of an indexed array
>   evaluates to a number less than zero, it is interpreted as relative to
>   one greater than the maximum index of the array, so negative indices
>   count back from the end of the array, and an index of -1 refers to the
>   last element.

E.g.:

```
declare -i i=1 # -i declares integer
${arr[i*2]} 
${arr[-1]} #returns last element
${arr[0]}  #first element is at index 0
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Unfortunately it is not quite clear what your answer refers to. The solution to the OPs question was indeed that the array was incorrectly initialized with a comma-separated list instead of a space-separated one. Also, neither the question nor any of the answers uses a `$`-style dereferencing of the array index. Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/578746/edit) your answer to clarify its scope.

Comment: @AdminBee The question asked is "How do I access an item of an array in shell?" which I answered.

Comment: @AdminBee In spite of no one using `$` indexing I still thought it important to mention.

Comment: No, the issue is that the user gets `1,2` when expecting `1`. You don't even mention why this is or what to do about it. Accessing the first element of the array is something the user is already doing _correctly_.

Comment: @Kusalananda This was already answered by another poster. I arrived at this question by googling and found the answer I was looking for missing. codeforester provided some more details but didn't include everything. I tried to complete it. Btw neither does his answer mention the OP's problem.

Comment: At least that answer shows how to assign to an array. Also, it would be easy for you to fix your answer and to make it relevant to the question.

Comment: I tried to edit your answer in that direction, feel free to improve.

Comment: @Kusalananda Now that you edited the question my answer has indeed become unrelated to it. Moving the goalposts.

Comment: @Roland I made the _title_ relevant to the question. I never edited the text of the question, so the question remains the same.